# What does y=np.zeros(len(x)) do in this function definition?

Tags: python, numpy

Learning data visualisation with python and numpy, provided with an example in a Jupyter notebook

What does  `y=np.zeros(len(x))` do in this definition? Set y = 0?

```py
x=np.linspace(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,100)


# i-th order sine series decomposition
from math import factorial
def sineseries(x,order):
    y=np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(order):
        y=y+(-1.)**i/factorial(2*i+1)*x**(2*i+1)
    return y

for i in range(20):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,sineseries(x,i),'.')
    plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'k')
```

Comment: It's just creating an initial array with only zeros like [0, 0, 0, ...]. It has as many elements as x.

Comment: I thought as much, is it taking into consideration that I might enter more than one value into the argument x?

Comment: yes. Numpy arrays support most math operations elementwise

Answer (score 1):

It creates an array with `len(x)` zeros.

For example if x has 3 elements then the resulting array will be `[0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Just added an example.